# iOS User Interface for different devices in iPhone 4, 5, 6+ and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, user-interface, screen-resolution

From what I know the resolution in iPad is higher than iPhone therefore the same width and height point in storyboard in iPhone will appear to be bigger in iPad. However, I didn't notice the size differences and it seems to be the same which look the same in iPad.**(the height of textfield)**

Are there any ways for making them scale in the same aspect fit? By right elements in iPad should be bigger due to the resolution. Autolayout has been used in the following picture.

[image]

How do I code for user interface for iPhone 4 and iPhone 6+? The same box will appeared to be too big in iPhone 4.

Comment: Provided you have followed the HIG then everything will be OK. Something that is 44 points high in an iPhone will be approximately the same size in an iPad but still 44 points high. Also, if you are following the HIG and allowing Dynamic Type then the user can change the size of the text anyway which will change the size of your textfields. Have you actually tried your interface design and seen what i looks like on different devices?

Comment: May I know what is HIG? The textfield will be one of the example I used for testing but for uiview or other object will look the same size in iPad. I'm having trouble to explain the concept of point and pixel to my manager as he think the point in storyboard is suppose to be autoscaled to fit the iPhone 4, 5, 6,6+ and iPad aspect ratio.

Comment: The HIG is the iOS Human Interface Guidelines. It is an Apple document that describes how you should design UI for iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ . Points are not autoscaled they are defined by the hardware in each device. For a discussion on pixels versus points see the iOS Drawing Concepts document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html

Comment: @RoboticCat Thank you. Is there a chance I can set the width ratio of the three textfield in 2:7:1 if the width?

Comment: Yes.  You can set the width of something as a ratio to something else. You need to use Autolayout and Constraints; this is recommended by Apple anyway due to Dynamic Type and Adaptive Layouts.  Make sure you read the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) and watch some of the WWDC 2013 (https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/) and WWDC 2014 videos (https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) on Autolayout as they will help you understand how to use it correctly.